# Adapting Bohr Model with a photon

Tags: black-holes, atomic-physics

This is for my final exam prep, the answers are not listed so I am coming here for help.

Adapting the Bohr model, consider a photon of energy E orbiting in a circle around a black hole of mass $Mb$. Assume Newtonian gravity $F = GMbMp/r^2$ where $Mb$ is the mass of the black hole and $Mp$ is the mass of the photon.

a) what is the gravitational mass of the photon $Mp$?

I am assuming for this question that the photon is at rest

$E=mc^2 = hf$

$m=hf/c^2$

b) Using force balance, what is the radius of the orbit of the photon, R? [all of the mass of the black hole must be within R]

Since I am told to adapt the Bohr Model, I am assuming I'm supposed to adapt the $r=n^2h^2/MeKe^2$ for finding the radius. For this question should I simply change $Me$ to $Mp$? Also how do I take into account $e$, the elementary charge since it is a proton. As protons have $0$ charge then the radius isn't possible.

c) Quantizing the angular momentum, what photon energies are allowed, $En$? [use the same quantization than the Bohr model]

I know that angular momentum is $l=Mevr =nh$ and that $En=-13.6/n^2 eV$

I've never encountered a problem where I am asked what is allowed in terms of the Bohr Model. Where should I start with this problem?

d) Using $En$, what are the wavelengths $\lambda n$ of the photons, and how many wavelengths fit along the circumference of the circular orbit of each n?

I have no idea how to do this question.

For all of these I am looking for ways to start them. I am using this for exam prep and I don't want the full answer just where to start or a different wording to help me understand the problem a bit better.

Comment: What do you consider to be the **mass of the photon**? It is well known that the photon has no rest mass. You have to be very careful here. The theoretical physics big shots on this site will mercilessly accuse you of heresy and possibly downgrade or put on hold your question if you mention "outdated" concepts such as **relativistic mass**, especially in relation to the photon.

Answer (score 2):

(b) is not about the Bohr model yet. It is just a classical approach for balancing forces. Which forces are there? There is surely Newtonian gravity, as stated initially, but what else?

(c) only tells you to quantize the classical momentum L. In other words, calculate L and assume it is written as $L=n\hbar$ with $n$ an integer. This means only some values of L are "allowed" by this assumption. What about energies? This assumption surely "allows" only some specific energies ...

(d) Once you have "allowed" energies, don't you have "allowed" frequencies? So what about wavelengths? How do frequency and wavelength relate?

Comment: Thank you so much :). for a) The only other force I can think of affecting something going in a circular motion is centripetal force.

b) would the only energies allowed would be energies not equal to $0$? If that is the case would I still use the value of $e$ since putting in $0$ for a charge doesn't make a whole lot of sense when it will make the energy $0$ every time.

Comment: How do you get the energy to be 0? With the knowledge of the angular momentum, can you obtain a kinetic energy?